# Find average number of ranges including current date over a period

Tags: google-sheets

I take notes in Google Sheets of the dates when I buy and sell stocks. I would like to know the average number of companies I own stock in on a day.

I have one column for the buy date, and another column for the sell date. Each row represents stock in a specific company. The period holding a stock may range from a few weeks up to many months. I always buy stock for the same amount, and I always buy all the stocks at the buy date and sell all the stocks at the sell date.

This is my actual data (except from the company names). Where there is no "Sell date", I still own the stock.

| Company | Buy date | Sell date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-07-06 |  |
| 2 | 2020-07-07 | 2020-09-23 |
| 3 | 2020-07-08 | 2020-08-21 |
| 4 | 2020-07-20 | 2020-10-08 |
| 5 | 2020-08-08 |  |
| 6 | 2020-08-19 | 2020-09-02 |
| 7 | 2020-09-03 | 2020-09-23 |
| 8 | 2020-09-23 |  |
| 9 | 2020-09-23 |  |
| 10 | 2020-09-23 |  |
| 11 | 2020-09-23 |  |
| 12 | 2020-10-07 | 2020-12-29 |
| 13 | 2020-10-15 | 2020-12-16 |
| 14 | 2020-10-15 | 2020-11-17 |
| 15 | 2020-11-17 |  |
| 16 | 2020-11-17 |  |
| 17 | 2020-11-17 |  |
| 18 | 2020-12-08 | 2020-12-29 |
| 19 | 2020-12-11 |  |
| 20 | 2020-12-11 |  |
| 21 | 2020-12-29 |  |
| 22 | 2021-01-11 |  |
| 23 | 2021-01-11 |  |

The algorithm would be: For each date between 2020-07-06 and today, check how many ranges include that date. Then calculate the average of all those values.

I realize I can currently do this manually, but this table will continue to grow over many years and I would like it automated.

I have searched this website and the search engines and have not been able to find a solution or any similar problem posted. If I have done a bad job searching, I am happily guided to any solutions you are able to find online. I have also read about the different formulas available in Google Sheets and have not really been able to come up with any strategy to solve my problem.

[Here is a Google Sheets demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dqi0LLdNofu8fzQmGaJvk1ePLvgd-p3-AmH8hNa3kc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos Thank you, I should of course have done that from the beginning. Question now updated with a link to a test sheet. If any other information is required, please just ask and I will answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the test sheet. I must admit though I still fail to understand how you get those values and using `....` does not really help.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, this was harder to explain than I first realized. I have added more comments i the test sheet. Please let me know if it is still unclear. I used the dots because I did not want to have several hundreds of dates in the sheet, but I modified it now to make the example smaller.

Comment: Did you possibly have any insight or ideas on how to solve this @marikamitsos?

Comment: Sorry I did not. Please read [my latest comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150864/find-average-number-of-ranges-including-current-date-over-a-period?noredirect=1#comment137551_150864). The issue is still unclear to me despite your explanations. In other words: *Numbers don't add up*

Comment: @marikamitsos Ah ok, even with all the added explanations I added in the Test sheet?